# PHP - Find File in Directory By File Name

Tags: php, select, directory, filenames

I have a directory full of filenames that contain unix timestamps.

```
file_1434320602.data
file_1434320352.data
file_1434320112.data
file_1434320032.data
```

How would I get about loading them up in PHP so that I can select the one which I needed?

Comment: `glob()` would be a good place to start. S.O questions should include code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do it. The simplest in this case is `glob`:

```
$files = glob('/path/to/file_*.data');
print_r($files);
```